# Can I use telegram api for my commercial app?

Tags: telegram

I'm more confused how to use Telegram MTProto API, but still I want to know the truth, Can I use telegram API for mobile number verification or sending messages in my own commercial app(not related to telegram)?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use telegram API for mobile number verification

I don't think so.

> or sending messages in my own commercial app(not related to telegram)?

You can use Telegram Bot APIs (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). In this case (bot service), Telegram is very open and explicitely declared to me the freedom to use Bot apps for commercial/profit purposes: see my twitter page: http://www.twitter.com/solyarisoftware !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use channels for commercial messages.

Answer (score 0):

your Question is Unclear


Actually, you can Create your own commercial app for yourself

to do that, you should use Telegram API, so your app is related to telegram

But it's completely not related to the telegram application you use now

for example mobile apps or windows application



Now, you write your own commercial app

you should Authenticate your phoneNumber with your own app

So, You should use telegram API for mobile number verification


Good Luck !!!